# How to multiply two openCV matrices in a kernel function in CUDA?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, cuda

I have the following minimal piece of code and would like to know how I can multiply two matrices in my kernel function?
I can eg not create a Mat (like in openCV) in the kernel function.

```
  __global__ void myMatKernel(int N, Mat *b)
  {
       Mat a;   // creates compilation error 1

      // b = a*b;      <---- what I would need


  }

  int main (void)
  {
        Mat a(10, 1, CV_64F);
        a.setTo(Scalar(2.2));
        Mat c(1, 10, CV_64F);
        c.setTo(Scalar(3.35));
        Mat d;

        d = a*c;    // works perfectly fine, but would like to do this operation on the GPU

        Mat *b;
        cudaMallocManaged(&b, sizeof(Mat));
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
       //assign somehow values to matrix b before passing it to the function

        myMatKernel<<<1,256>>>(1, b) ;   
        cudaFree(b);
  }
```

compilation error 1: "error: calling a __host__ function("cv::Mat::Mat") from a __global__ funcction("myKernel") is not allowed"

Could someone explain/show how I can solve these issues?

Comment: you can't "solve" them, OpenCV code isn't intended to be used in the way you are trying to

Comment: @talonmies updated my post to more precisely show what I want to achieve. In case openCV code isn't intended to be used in this way, what alternative do I have? What would be the correct way to do this? I have a vector of mats and would like to paralelize that.

Comment: Have you tried [tag:eigen]? Most of its core functionality is cuda compatible.

Comment: So what is your real user case? No one would bother using CUDA with an outer product of two length 10 vectors. What is sensible depends on what your real use case is

Comment: @talonmies actually I have a vector of 30 Mats (with varying sizes). Any idea about how I can solve the above mentionned issue?

Comment: That sounds like an extremely poor fit for the GPU unless your "various" sizes are large. The GPU is very good at doing a large number of identical operations in parallel, but it is not good for a small number of dissimilar operations in parallel.

Comment: Please look at [this post](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-write-a-custom-cuda-kernel-with-opencv-as-host-library/) I wrote a few years back which shows how to interop between OpenCV and your custom CUDA kernel. Complete source code is attached at the end.

Comment: @trilolil: You might be surprised. There is a lot of fixed costs associated with transferring data to and from the GPU and calling APIs to run kernels, etc. Unless the problem sizes are large, you will find that it *won't* be "better" than serial operations on the CPU for the cases where the vectors involved are small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OpenCV allocates host memory for `cv::Mat`, you can't use `Mat` and related OpenCV APIs in a kernel as you would have used it in a host code. So you have to write your own kernel for your matrix multiplication.

OpenCV provides a class called `cv::cuda::GpuMat`. OpenCV allocates device memory for them. However, APIs related to `GpuMat` are meant to be used in host code. For matrix multiplication you have to write your own kernel anyway.

However I sometimes find some APIs for `GpuMat` convenient, such as allocating device memory using its constructor and copying data between host matrix and device matrix using `download()` and `upload()`. Also, `Gpumat` class keeps your matrix's attributes such as `rows`, `cols`, `type()`, `step`, etc. in a single structure. This may come in handy for some cases.

Following sample code uses `GpuMat`.

```
int main (void)
{
    Mat a{ 10, 1, CV_64FC1 }; // 10x1 matrix
    Mat b{ 1, 10, CV_64FC1 }; // 1x10 matrix
    Mat c{ 10, 10, CV_64FC1 }; // multiplying a and b results in 10x10 matrix
    a.setTo(Scalar(2.2f));
    b.setTo(Scalar(3.35f));

    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_a{ a.rows, a.cols, CV_64FC1 };
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_b{ b.rows, b.cols, CV_64FC1 };
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_c{ c.rows, c.cols, CV_64FC1 };

    d_a.upload(a);
    d_b.upload(b);

    MatMul<<<1, dim3(c.cols, c.rows)>>>((double*)d_a.data, d_a.step,
                                        (double*)d_b.data, d_b.step,
                                        (double*)d_c.data, d_c.step,
                                        a.cols);

    d_c.download(c);
}

__global__ void MatMul(const double* const a, const int a_step,
                       const double* const b, const int b_step,
                       double* const c, const int c_step,
                       const int a_cols)
{
    int c_row = threadIdx.y;
    int c_col = threadIdx.x;

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a_cols; i++)
        sum += ((double*)((unsigned char*)a + c_row * a_step))[i]
             * ((double*)((unsigned char*)b + i * b_step))[c_col];

    ((double*)((unsigned char*)c + c_row * c_step))[c_col] = sum;
    
}
```

Note that if the number of elements of `c`, the result matrix, exceeds the maximum number of threads in a block(1024 for cc >= 2.0), this code won't work. Kernel should be designed differently.

---

#### EDIT

```
((double*)((unsigned char*)c + c_row * c_step))[c_col];
```

The above statement access `c_row`-th row and `c_col`-th column element of matrix `c`. This matrix is a single channel matrix and the element type is double. It's step is given by `c_step`. In OpenCV, step refers to the number of bytes allocated per row. It is larger than or equal to the total size of actual pixels in each row to meet memory alignment, which in turn makes memory access faster.

The above statement first casts `c` (which is of type `double*`) to `unsigned char*`, since `c_step` is counted in bytes. Adding `c_row * c_step` to `(unsigned char*)c` gives pointer to the 0-th column of `c_row`-th row. It now casts the pointer to `double*` to access `c_col`-th column with standard array access operator `[]`.

Comment: Why should I rather pass GpuMat's instead of normal Mat's to the kernel functions? What if I wanted to pass a vector of Mat's all at once to the kenrel function?

Comment: @trilolil Answer edited. You don't pass `GpuMat` itself to kernel, because `GpuMat` _class_ itself is allocated in host memory. And the `GpuMat` _class_ itself is designed to be used on host code. However, the _actual matrix data_ is allocated in device memory. Also, as the edited answer says, OpenCV allocates host memory for `Mat` and kernels cannot access that host memory. `Mat` class is designed to be used on CPU. You have no choice but to pass pointers to kernel and handle the data yourself.

Comment: @trilolil Do you know what a "step" is in terms of image processing?

Comment: I guess that s just going from one pixel to the next pixel.

Comment: @trilolil No, actually it is the number of bytes on each row. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Is there any possibility to send an entire vector of Mats at once to a kernel function in stead of having to send one Mat at a time?

Comment: In OpenCV api, not that I know of. I'm affraid that you'll have to make such function.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i could not send Mat object to CUDA kernel, i overcame this problem by using the pointer of the image in the Mat class (.data) as an argument instead,

So the code will be: (i have not compiled it)

```
  __global__ void myMatKernel(double *d_a, double *d_b)
   {
     //index of this pixel
     int j = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x; //width
     int i = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y; //height

  // b = a*b;      <---- what I would need


   }

  int main (void)
  {
    Mat a(10, 1, CV_64F);
    a.setTo(Scalar(2.2));
    Mat c(1, 10, CV_64F);
    c.setTo(Scalar(3.35));
    Mat d;
    double* d_a;
    double* d_b;




    d = a*c;    // works perfectly fine, but would like to do this  operation on the GPU

    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_a, (a.rows)*(a.cols)*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_b, (b.rows)*(b.cols)*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a.data, (a.rows)*(a.cols)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b.data, (b.rows)*(b.cols)*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   //assign somehow values to matrix b before passing it to the function

    myMatKernel<<<1,256>>>(a,b) ;   
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
  }
```

I have been using CUDA with openCV, check this [code](https://github.com/misaleh/Free-space-and-obstacle-detection/blob/master/Occupancy_GPU.cu), it is for computing occupancy grid from disparity map(its function is irrelevant, check its structure as it may be helpful)

Comment: for using GpuMat in kernel code you can check https://www.programmersought.com/article/69363942435/