# how to access pixel in OpenCV Cuda (GpuMat)

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, pixel, gpu

```
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(1920,1080,CV_8UC4); //it's an example (I use image have 4 channel)
cv::Vec4b& pixel = image.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j) // i and j is rows and cols
```

I want to use Cuda(GpuMat) and there is no ".at"

how can I change my code for accessing the pixels

Answer (score 3):

The `cv::cuda::GpuMat` class has it's data live on the GPU/device, and this cannot be directly accessed by CPU/host code. This is why there is no equivalent to `cv::Mat.at()`. Transferring data between the host and device is slow, and doing a per pixel operation on a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` would therefore be far slower than on a `cv::Mat`.

It is however possible to write CUDA kernels which perform per-pixel operations. I'm afraid that while I can't give good advice on this, that this is apparently doable and there are answers to similar problems [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174092/how-to-multiply-two-opencv-matrices-in-a-kernel-function-in-cuda) that might be able to help you.

Outside of that depending on exactly what you need to do there might be a build in function that does something similar.