# What causes this segmentation fault (core dumped) error at cudaMemcpy when copying to GPU?

Tags: c++, cuda, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to fix segmentation fault (core dumped) error messages with a toy program when calling cudaMemcpy. It works for small images, but for bigger images it normally fails; I say normally, because it has sometimes succeeded when debugging with valgrind (more about that below). I have looked at similar questions, but have been unable to find the answer; sorry if this is a duplicate! I am just learning out (and following programming massively parallel processors).

Here is my code, cleaned up:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

__global__ void
colorToGreyKernel(unsigned char* outPic, unsigned char* inPic, unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
  // printf("trying \n" );

  int Col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  int Row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

  if( Col < width && Row < height){

    int greyOffset = Row * width + Col;

    int rgbOffset = greyOffset * 3;

    unsigned char b = inPic[rgbOffset];
    unsigned char g = inPic[rgbOffset +1];
    unsigned char r = inPic[rgbOffset +2];

    outPic[greyOffset] = 0.21f*r + 0.71f*g + 0.07f*b;
  }
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
  bool test = code == cudaSuccess;
  // cout << "code " << std::boolalpha<< test;
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      // const char *errorStr = NULL;
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    unsigned int imSize[2] = {400,400};
    unsigned char* inPic = NULL;
    unsigned char* outPic = NULL;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&inPic, imSize[0] * imSize[1] * 3 * sizeof(CV_8U)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&outPic, imSize[0] * imSize[1] * sizeof(CV_8U)));
    image = imread( argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR );

    resize(image, image, Size(imSize[0],imSize[1]));

    Mat greyImg(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8U, Scalar(125));

    size_t size = image.cols * image.rows * image.channels() * sizeof(CV_8U);
    // This is where it always fails for bigger images
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(inPic,(void*) &image.data[0], size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(outPic, (void*)&greyImg.data[0], size/3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 dimGrid(ceil(image.rows/16.0),ceil(image.cols/16.0),1);
    dim3 dimBlock(16,16,1);

    colorToGreyKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(outPic, inPic,(int) image.rows,(int) image.cols);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(greyImg.data, outPic, size / 3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", greyImg);

    waitKey(0);
    cudaFree(&inPic[0]);
    cudaFree(&outPic[0]);
    return 0;
  }
```

I'm able to allocate on the device, but the copying fails for bigger images. I've tried it using opencv::cuda, and I can load any picture and do cvtColor on the device without resizing, so I conclude it's not memory (similar when looking at nvidia-smi).

When I run using valgrind, I get a lot of Invalid write of size 8 errors around this point, all referencing to libcuda. I know it's this particular memcopy that's the problem, by isolating it. Sometimes it also works in valgrind, but I've gathered that this is normal. I don't have experience with valgrind yet, but the memory issues don't make sense to me (I'm trying to copy *to the device*, so why a segmentation fault which is related to the host?).

My question is simple, where does the error come from and how to fix this?

NVCC = 11.1
gpu = GeForce GTX 960M (not a lot, but that shouldn't matter)

Again, I am new to programming in Cuda, but have tried what I can think of and can not isolate the problem! Thanks for your help.

Comment: the problem here is your usage of OpenCV, not CUDA.  an item like `CV_8U` is [not a type](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html), it is a compiler `#define`.  Therefore `sizeof(CV_8U)` is not doing what you think it is doing.  As a result of that, your calculation of `size` is wrong.  As a result of that, when the `cudaMemcpy` operation attempts to access `&image.data[0]` for `size` bytes, you are overrunning the end of the buffer.  For a large enough `size` calculation  (large enough image) you will hit a seg fault.  This basically has nothing to do with CUDA.

Comment: As a simple fix, just delete `* sizeof(CV_8U)` everywhere that you have it, and your code will likely work correctly.

Comment: That fix did work, and explained the problems with my code. sizeof(CV_8U) is of size 4, rather than sizeof(unsigned int) == 1. Thanks!

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned int)` is not 1.

Comment: sorry, meant unsigned char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here relates to your usage of OpenCV.  An item like `CV_8U` is [not a type](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html), it is a compiler `#define`. Therefore `sizeof(CV_8U)` is not doing what you think it is doing. Your intended usage should be to capture the size of the underlying type (e.g. `unsigned char`, i.e. a type size of 1).  However, `sizeof(CV_8U)` returns evidently the size of an integer, which is 4.

As a result of that, your calculation of `size` is wrong (4x too large). As a result of that, when the `cudaMemcpy` operation attempts to access `&image.data[0]` for `size` bytes, it will attempt to copy past the end of the buffer.  For small images, the overrun doesn't trigger the run time check/limit. For a large enough `size` calculation (large enough image) you will hit a seg fault. Although the failure is triggered within a CUDA call, the origin of the error is outside of CUDA.

One possible solution is to replace your usage of `sizeof(CV_8U)` with something like `sizeof(unsigned char)`.  Since that size is 1, you can also just delete the multiplication by `sizeof(CV_8U)` and get the same behavior.

You can also avoid this sort of allocation and let OpenCV do the allocation (and host-device data copying) work for you as demonstrated in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219634/1695960) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517906/opencv-copy-gpumat-into-cuda-device-data)